# Unable to use Llama Index with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, openai-api, chatgpt-api, llama-index

I am using Llama Index to create a custom bot using AWS Lambda, but when I try to create its layer and upload it to the AWS layer, I am getting "package not found" errors for different libraries. I tried to delete some packages from the Llama Index package and use AWS packages like Pandas and NumPy, but I got a "max size" error.

I created the package using WSL2 Ubuntu.

this is the error I got when I try to use layer

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_handler': Unable to import required dependencies:\nnumpy: \n\nIMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!\n\nImporting the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for\nmany reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was\ninstalled.\n\nWe have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:\n\n    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html\n\nPlease note and check the following:\n\n  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from \"/var/lang/bin/python3.8\"\n  * The NumPy version is: \"1.24.2\"\n\nand make sure that they are the versions you expect.\nPlease carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.\n\nOriginal error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'\n",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

sample code

```
import json
from llama_index import GPTSimpleVectorIndex
import os
import boto3



def lambda_handler(event, context): 
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    #added key
    try:
        event = json.loads(event['body'])
        prompt = event.get("prompt", None)
        if(prompt is None):
            raise Exception("prompt is None")

        bucket_name = ''
        object_key = ''
        index_object = s3.Object(bucket_name, object_key)
        index_content = index_object.get()['Body'].read()
        index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex.load_from_disk(index_content)
        # Query the index
        RESPONSE = index.query(prompt)

        return {
            "headers": {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST"
            },
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": json.dumps(
                {'message': json.dumps({"message": RESPONSE})}
            )
        }
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return {
            "headers": {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST"
            },
            "statusCode": 500,
            "body": json.dumps(
                {'message': json.dumps(e, default=str)}
            )
        }
```

I tried to fix the issue by removing libraries from the Llama Index package and using AWS custom libraries, but the errors kept occurring. First, the error was for NumPy, and I added the AWS NumPy package to fix it. Then, I got an error for Pandas and tried using the AWS Pandas library, and then I tried using numexpr. However, I started getting a "max size for layers" error.

more explanations :

The Llama-Index package originally contained the NumPy package, but I encountered an error with it (which I have mentioned in my question). I removed NumPy from the Llama-Index package and tried using the AWSLambda-Python38-SciPy1x package from the AWS layer, which fixed the NumPy error. However, a new error appeared: "No module named 'pandas._libs.interval'". To resolve this, I added the AWSPandasSDK layer from AWS, but the combined layer size exceeded AWS's limit. To overcome this limitation, I removed the previously added NumPy package and added the AWSPandasSDK layer instead, which fixed the NumPy and Pandas issues. However, I encountered a new error: "No module named numexpr", even though all of these libraries were already present in the AWS Llama-Index package.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you added the AWS numpy package?? Did you add the layer to the lambda?

Comment: Or if you're not using layers / docker in lambda, check out https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible

Comment: @luk2302 please look at question I have added more explanation section

Comment: @erik258 I am not using docker